# Click Counter on badgeText

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, counter

Can someone guide me how to correct this code to create clickable button counter Badge in Chrome extension? Right now it is rising rapidly, but I need to raise only when I click on a button what was named "done".

background.js

```
var i = 1;

function updateIcon() {
    i = 1;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: ''
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "popup.html"
    });
}


chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
    color: [200, 0, 0, 100]
});

window.setInterval(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: String(i)
    });
    i++;
}, 4000);
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //Get Reference to Functions
    backGround = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    //Call Function
    backGround.updateIcon();
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Bagde",
    "description": 
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Clickable Badge",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need html code for this button. But you can use any button you like.

Comment: Uhm, obviously you need to remove setInterval and add a click listener for the "done" button that will increment `backGround.i` and invoke setBadgeText.

Comment: Hey, Yes I found that too, but I am still one of the rookie here, can you give me more detail?

Comment: When do you actually want to run `updateIcon();`? Why do you run it when the popup loads if you want the button, where is the btn located?

Comment: I want to run it like the others extensions are for example AdBlock. For me this extension is the best way to see how many clicks I made on a specific button. The button class is: class="processing-button" it is a normal button used to be clicked. I need to have information how many clicks I made in a day on that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a content-script in order to handle clicks and send a message about that event to a background script, which will change badge icon text.

Here is the solution. It works for Google's "Google Search" button.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Click counter",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
      }
    ],

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Click counter"
    }
}
```

**content-script.js**

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.matches('input[type="submit"]')) { // your button
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('clicked')
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```js
let counter = 0;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    if(message === 'clicked') {
        counter += 1;
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: counter.toString()
        });
    }
});
```

Don't forget to configure "matches" URL for your website.

Comment: Hello Deliaz, Thank you for your time to give me that code, I am thinking that I am doing something wrong. In the manifest I added website as you told me for example: "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"], in the button I added my button examplle: if(e.target.matches('search')). Yes I know that I am just a rookie in javascript but can you once more point me to good solution?

Comment: @Mkik, the code above is already tuned for the google website and works out of the box. You can read more about [Match](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) patterns. And here about [element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Comment: Deliaz you make my day. This link what you provided told me what exactly needs to be done. I forgot to use # as id and . as class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Deliaz I want to reopen this question due to issue what I found. Counter working perfectly due to one circumstance, when you are waiting too long or using few Tabs sometimes counter is reset to 1, I know that this is probably that the numbers are not stored anywhere. I found solution that you can store in Chrome memory numbers. I wanted to ask here not to open another question regarding this situation, what variable is best to use here?

Comment: @Mkik, yes, you right. There is my mistake. It is happening because of `"persistent": false` in the manifest file. This directive switches background page to an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/event_pages). The first way to solve it ti set `persistent: true` (or simply remove it). The other option is to use localStorage or [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to keep latest value. Also, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ha! Great news, thank you very much. I started to combine with chrome.storage.local but I don't have enough wisdom how to do this corretly,(I created new question how this can be added but I don't know how to load when I save it in local.storage) Mostly I check how others are 
 coding and try to modify my as well, but I couldn't find any answers with setBadgeText. Thank you very much for your support!